# erro Invalid App ID The specified 'fb:app:id' property is not a valid app ID

Tags: joomla

I'm getting this issue and not got a clue where it is coming from! I'm no coder at all and not at all sure what to do or where to start to narrow this issue down.

I have AddToAny App to share Facebook and I set up a Facebook App at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

but not added it to the site only added app id to one of the apps installed in Joomla! 3.8.11  so this is why I'm confused!

I can get Open Graph properties to show up ok and seems to be working using Tagz, apart from the error showing up (Invalid App ID
The specified 'fb:app:id' property is not a valid app ID.) I can also use Twitter with no errors or issues sharing pages!

Can anyone help me find where I'm not set up correctly? I also cannot edit the index.php file to add code!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure the issue!

I had put a space before the Facebook ID number when I was adding it into the Tagz App in Joomla, after I took the space away it's showing up with no errors! In Facebook debugger.